# Outlook sending attachments as winmail.dat

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

We have a customer who can only receive plain text emails, i have change the settings in outlook and email are sent ok, but if we add an attachment they receive it as a winmail.dat file.

I have changed the registry keys, cleared the cache, recreated the profile and ran the fix it tool.

The email is definitely being sent as plan text by the attachment shows as,
Content-Type: application/ms-tnef; name="winmail.dat"

Comment: Are you directly sending to a smtp-server or are you attached to a Exchange-server? Exchange server have the tendency to re-format a mail to RTF resulting in a `winmail.dat`. Only recipients with Outlook can read those (other then some tools on the internet where you need to upload the `winmail.dat` to translate it, there are local tools too) There is a option in Exchange to prevent this if you have control over the server.

Comment: Yes its connected to an exchange server, we have 4 users who email this customer and 2 are ok but the other 2 have this problem, it only happens when they attach a file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can follow this guide from Microsoft:
[How to Prevent the Winmail.dat File from Being Sent to Internet Users](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/138053)

---

If you have control over the Exchange server you need to change
`Send Microsoft Exchange Rich Text` and set it to `Never`:

- Open the `Internet Mail Connector`-Properties page.
- Click the `General`-tab.
- The `Send Microsoft Exchange Rich Text` list box controls the sending of rich-text data.
  Set this value to `Never`.

If you don't have control over your Exchange server you could try the following:

- You need to add the recipient to you address book.
- There you should be able to clear the checkbox for
  `Always Send To This Recipient In Microsoft Exchange Rich-Text Format`

If this still does not work there are some other methods you could try in the link above.
Some of these options also depend on the version of Exchange (so if they don't work we need more detail to resolve the issue).

Another good resource to resolving the sending of `winmail.dat` is [here](http://www.slipstick.com/problems/outlook-is-sending-winmail-dat-attachments/).

Comment: The address book method didn't work so i changed the mail connector setting on the server and it has solved the problem, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you have an Exchange Server 2013, you can also disable winmail.dat filename generation:

Get-RemoteDomain | Set-RemoteDomain -TNEFEnabled $False

Here is an example:

[Exchange Server 2013: Ficheros adjuntos winmail.dat](http://www.sysadmit.com/2014/01/Exchange-Server-2013-Ficheros-adjuntos-winmail-dat.html)

It's in Spanish, but with screenshoots, it's easy to understand.